# In Windows, how can I view a list of all window titles ?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In Windows, how can I view a list of all the titles of all Windows that are open.

(Preferably with some unique identifier like handle)

Comment: There's a Windows API function to do that called [EnumWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that has the core functionality required. I know of no existing program to do that, but you could probably write one in your favorite scripting language -- I personally prefer [Python](http://python.org), which could certainly do something like this. VisualBasic probably could, too, as well as a number of others.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [EnumWindows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function. It will invoke the application-defined callback function argument passed to it for all the top-level windows on the screen, passing it the handle of each one, until the callback returns `FALSE`.

Here's a simple Python 2.x console program I wrote that uses that function (and a few others to determine which windows might actually be visible on the desktop -- many of the "top-level" windows that`EnumWindows()`enumerates over are invisible -- to accomplish what you want. It makes use of the `win32gui`module included in the [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) extension package to gain access to the Windows API. This can also be done at a lower, more direct, level using the built-in`ctypes`module, but PyWin32 is a more advanced and convenient way to go about it, IMO.

You could redirect the output to a text file or the program could be modified to display the list in a window or dialog box using several different GUI modules available, including the tk/tcl interface module called`Tkinter`, which comes standard with the language.

```python
import sys
import win32gui

def callback(hwnd, strings):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        window_title = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
        left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
        if window_title and right-left and bottom-top:
            strings.append('0x{:08x}: "{}"'.format(hwnd, window_title))
    return True

def main():
    win_list = []  # list of strings containing win handles and window titles
    win32gui.EnumWindows(callback, win_list)  # populate list

    for window in win_list:  # print results
        print window

    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

I took the PowerShell script from [Enumerating all Windows-windows with a PowerShell function and a callback function](http://powershell-knowhow.de/powershell/?p=321) and modified it slightly.

It print the window name and handle.

```
<#
 .Synopsis
 Enumerieren der vorhandenen Fenster
#>

$TypeDef = @"

using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Api
{

 public class WinStruct
 {
   public string WinTitle {get; set; }
   public int WinHwnd { get; set; }
 }

 public class ApiDef
 {
   private delegate bool CallBackPtr(int hwnd, int lParam);
   private static CallBackPtr callBackPtr = Callback;
   private static List<WinStruct> _WinStructList = new List<WinStruct>();

   [DllImport("User32.dll")]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   private static extern bool EnumWindows(CallBackPtr lpEnumFunc, IntPtr lParam);

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

   private static bool Callback(int hWnd, int lparam)
   {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
       int res = GetWindowText((IntPtr)hWnd, sb, 256);
      _WinStructList.Add(new WinStruct { WinHwnd = hWnd, WinTitle = sb.ToString() });
       return true;
   }   

   public static List<WinStruct> GetWindows()
   {
      _WinStructList = new List<WinStruct>();
      EnumWindows(callBackPtr, IntPtr.Zero);
      return _WinStructList;
   }

 }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $TypeDef -Language CSharpVersion3

[Api.Apidef]::GetWindows() | Where-Object { $_.WinTitle -ne "" } | Sort-Object -Property WinTitle | Select-Object WinTitle,@{Name="Handle"; Expression={"{0:X0}" -f $_.WinHwnd}}
```

Comment: Have you read the section about copyright on the site's imprint? It forbids copying, modifying and distributing all contents. You should at least consider giving fair attribution to the author.

Comment: @ComFreek: More fair than linking to the authors site?